# django urls throwing error in browser

Tags: python, django

i switched from the general url format to creating a urls.py file for each app so after moving the urls I get an error `Reverse for 'trending' not found. 'trending' is not a valid view function or pattern name`

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin

app_name = 'posts'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^trending/$', views.trending, name='trending'),
    url(r'^ranking/$', views.post_ranking, name='rank'),
    url(r'^create/$', views.create, name='create'),
]
```

**general urls.py**
`url(r'^', include('posts.urls' , namespace="posts")),`

**template**

```
<li><a href="{% url 'trending' %}"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"><small class="notification-badge">5</small></i> Trending</a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}"><i class="fa fa-level-down"></i> Recent</a></li>
```

additional codes would be added on request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work with this link in the template :

```
href="{% url 'posts:trending' %}"
```

and the same for the link below: `href="{% url 'polls:index' %}"`

---

[Reverse Namespace documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)